# Resample with specific condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that looks like the following:

```
Start date              Final date                      Value   ID    Serial     
2022-09-01 01:09:07.093 2022-09-01 05:43:55.092999999   10.92   200   120
2022-09-01 01:14:07.093 2022-09-01 05:43:55.092999999   10.92   200   120
2022-09-01 01:19:07.093 2022-09-01 05:43:55.092999999   10.92   200   120
2022-09-01 01:13:07.093 2022-09-01 03:41:55.092999999   11.85   201   122
...
2022-09-02 01:19:07.093 2022-09-03 07:43:55.092999999   7.35    300   124
2022-09-02 01:24:07.093 2022-09-03 07:43:55.092999999   7.35    300   124
...
```

For each match of "ID" and "Serial", the data is registered every five minutes from "Start date" until "End date".

I want to resample this dataframe on a 15 minutes basis and take the sum of "Value". My basic approach was:

```
df = df.resample('15min', on='Start date')['Value'].sum()
```

However, this counts each match of "ID" and "Serial" more than once per time interval. What I want is to resample the dataframe but considering just once each match of "ID" and "Serial" per 15 minutes gap.

For the given example, the output should look like the following (since the "ID" and "Serial" are repeated, the resample function should consider it just once per time gap):

```
Date                 Value                  
2022-09-01 01:00:00  22.70
2022-09-01 01:15:00  10.92
...
2022-09-02 01:15:00  7.35
...
```

Instead, what I get at the moment is:

```
Date                 Value                  
2022-09-01 01:00:00  33.69
2022-09-01 01:15:00  10.92
...
2022-09-02 01:15:00  14.7
...
```

Note: For each time gap I have lots of different "ID" and "Serial" combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a  [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) :

```
out = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Start date'))
         .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Serial'])['Value'].sum())
       )
```

Output:

```
Start date
2022-09-01 01:00:00    22.77
2022-09-01 01:15:00    10.92
2022-09-01 01:30:00     0.00
2022-09-01 01:45:00     0.00
2022-09-01 02:00:00     0.00
                       ...  
2022-09-02 00:15:00     0.00
2022-09-02 00:30:00     0.00
2022-09-02 00:45:00     0.00
2022-09-02 01:00:00     0.00
2022-09-02 01:15:00     7.35
Freq: 15T, Length: 98, dtype: float64
```

Comment: but if I drop the duplicates I will lose all values of ID and Serial that should be accounted for in other time gaps, don't I? the issue is that for each time gap it should be counted just once. But it could be the case that it needs to be considered in several time gaps

Comment: I just edited the question with an additional dataframe row showing this case

Comment: @OAP, got it, let me know if the update works for you